# How does the TARDIS know where to place objects it lands on inside?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

The Doctor’s TARDIS is small on the outside. When it lands on someone or something, how does it know exactly where to place them on the inside?

Why doesn't it, for instance, place what it lands on at a random location inside?

Comment: + 1 for "smaller on the outside"

Comment: Didn't know quite how to put it considering it lands on things that are bigger than it seen from the outside. For an instance in season 7 episode 6 when the TARDIS lands on clara, and she is longer than the tardis seen from the outside.

Comment: Because it's semi-sentient and capable of not landing stupidly.

Comment: I'd say landing on top of someone is stupid. And flying the TARDIS into hitlers office is also a bad idea

Comment: Wasn't it River who flew the TARDIS there? I'm not saying Doctor doesn't have ridiculous ideas, it's just that I don't remember this one being his.

Comment: With hitlers office, river shot the TARDIS, but the doctor flew it

Comment: Didn't TARDIS take Empire State Building inside once?

Comment: I believe it was the other way around. When the daleks tried to take over New York

Comment: Because the TARDIS can time travel and is sentient, it's gone into the future, read the script, then returned to the present and knows exactly where to place the item so it can be found yet not tripped over by cast or crew.

Comment: script - computer program(e.g. JavaScript) or the script with lines for the cast?

Comment: “Why doesn't it, for instance, place what it lands on at a random location inside?” — maybe it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In episode 4 of the 6th season, it is said that the tardis has a safety protocol that teleport its passengers to the main control room.
So If the tardis land on someone (or something) it maybe is the same protocol that make it appear directly in the control room ?

Answer (score 0):

If one considers the active control room as the "center" of the ship, as well as the most room where most of the important events are occurring, it's logical that any item landed on/around would appear there as a default.

IIRC, the first time something was landed on was Logopolis, where the TARDIS landed around what was assumed to be an ordinary Police box, for the purpose of taking many complex measurements.  It wasn't ordinary, and it resulted in many complex configurations.

Having said that, I would assume that if the settings were changed, an item could be set to appear in any room or location. If it were a hostile alien, they could land the capsule so that they would appear in a locked room far away from the control room.

Comment: This happens, also with the Master's TARDIS, in the earlier episode [_The Time Monster_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Monster).  See http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_ram